# R - Using maxdrawdown function with multiple Variables and grouping

Tags: r

Im using the maxdrawdown function in R and I am having difficulty in returning values by Variables.

Currently my Dataset looks like the following

```
VarA   VarB
Acc1    0.0209745492
Acc1    0.013020233
Acc1    0.001936364
Acc1    -0.000158368
Acc1    0.00870133
```

it works fine at the moment as the dataset is in the context of VarA which is the same var (Acc1) and when the maxdrawdown function is applied it returns exactly what I need `-0.02%`

```
maxdrawdown(mydataset$VarB)
```

What I need to do is to return a value for every different instant of VarA that will be in the dataset which is going to be circa 100k records

```
VarA    VarB
Acc1    0.0209745492
Acc1    0.013020233
Acc1    0.001936364
Acc1    -0.000158368
Acc1    0.00870133
Acc2    0.0209745492
Acc2    0.013020233
Acc2    0.001936364
Acc2    -0.000158368
Acc2    0.00870133
```

So my grouped return would resemple one result in VarA and the maxdradown result for the range of values in Varb

```
VarA  VarB (my maxdrawdown result)
Acc1  -0.02
Acc2  -0.45
Acc3  -0.002
Etc   Etc
```

any help would be fantastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

I'm not familiar with `maxDrawdown`. However, have a look at the `dplyr` package, it might give you what you want. Along the lines of;

```
library(dplyr)

OUTPUT <- Dataset %>% group_by(VarA) %>% mutate(Max = maxdrawdown(VarB))
```

This will group your dataset by `VarA` and then perform the `maxDrawdown` function on each group. It should work. However, it is hard to tell from the data you provide.

Also, please read the advice pages about what makes a good question, how to provide reproducible data, and specify which packages you are using to make it easier for people to offer answers in future.